# Capture App JSON Requests Android via Fiddler

Tags: android, ios, json, fiddler, wireshark

Recently I tried to figure out where the application Meet Mobile's data was being pulled from.  This is mostly out of curiosity as I noticed they have this free app for Android/iOS but nothing available from a computer which struck me as odd.

I set up fiddler on my computer with my phone using my computer as a proxy to access the internet, but when I do this Meet Mobile is not able to fetch data, even though I can use the browser to navigate the web without issue.  I followed this guide to set up my proxy:
http://www.cantoni.org/2013/11/06/capture-android-web-traffic-fiddler

I have discovered that the main site the data is being pulled from is https://awmobile.active.com/, and I believe it is being pulled via port 443.  However, I cannot figure out the correct syntax to query from this site (which I believe the application uses JSON).

Please let me know if there is a better way to go about capturing the web requests my application is sending off to its home base.  This is mostly an exercise of curiosity, and I'm excited to see what potential answers there are.

Cheers!

Comment: `Meet Mobile is not able to fetch data` Please explain what is actually happening. Do you see Meet Mobile calls in Fiddler?

Comment: I see the Meet Mobile calls in Fiddler, but the calls do not return any results with the app flashing "Network Communication Error" at the bottom. I am unsure of why this is happening as the phone allows me to use the browser without hindrance - however, if I try to browse via Chrome on my computer I get this result, "Cannot connect to the real www.google.com".
Here is a link to a screen capture of the Meet Mobile callouts:
[Meet Mobile Fiddler Imgur](http://imgur.com/ipUZk6v)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - I needed to install the Fiddler certificate on my Android phone for it to allow the connections.  I followed the steps listed here:
http://www.cantoni.org/2013/11/06/capture-android-web-traffic-fiddler

Thank you for your help and time!